# Noise showing up in the reflection of a plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

Is there anyway to easily remove this noise showing up in Cycles in the reflection of the plane? You can see it happening on the glass bottles right around where the "s" and "p" are in this JPG.
Turning off gloss in the ray visibility tab on the lights and plane work but then you lose a lot of other desirable qualities of the light. Thanks ahead of time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use the blender denoise compositing node nearly every time. It's super easy to setup. You'll need to enable the Denoising Data under the view layer properties first.

[image]

[image]